# button disabled prop not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a button with the "disabled" attribute, that I enable using jQuery when certain conditions are met. The problem is that Firefox doesn't read the "disabled" attribute, even though Chrome&IE have no problem.

My code is `<button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-secondary button_confirm" title="Title here">Confirm</button>`

I also tried `disabled=true` and `disabled=disabled` but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a verifiable example? Because [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bcj4Lqhn/) works in Firefox

Comment: strange enough, https://jsfiddle.net/4sh2ng5f/ seems to work for me in Firefox. The full page is at http://bencomp.rf.gd (button in question is second step, "Model deck si accesorii". I just verified it and it works fine there. Could it be because I'm running on xampp on localhost?

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out. The problem was that firefox stored my previous tries in cache, and javascript enabled the button because the condition was met (from previous tries). Thank you and sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not that the disabled property isn't read by Firefox, but that you're not modifying it properly using JQuery.

If you are using jQuery < 1.6, change the attribute using this command:

```
$('.button_confirm).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

If you are using jQuery >= 1.6, change the attribute using this command:

```
$('.button_confirm).prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just figured it out. The problem was that firefox stored my previous tries in cache, and javascript enabled the button because the condition was met (from previous tries). Thank you and sorry for wasting your time